# SQL Counts over time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about converting this code to one SQL query so I am not making a SQL query for ever time interval?

For everyhour over the last 12 hours get a count the number of total, successful, retry, and failed records... Seems simple but I am lost and at the limit of my sql knowledge.

I tried group by but that only give me hours where there are results.

Side note this is going to be a very large table: currently 300K rows for testing, but expect to have 500K to 1M rows inserted per day. With the lifetime of a row being purged after 14 or 30 days.

Using Mysql 8

Output

```
Results over Time
Current Time: 1598457808
Interval: 1598461200
Interval    Total   Success Retry   Failed
2020-08-26 12:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 11:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 10:00:00 104 77  22  5
2020-08-26 09:00:00 887 567 224 96
2020-08-26 08:00:00 1895    1274    408 213
2020-08-26 07:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 06:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 05:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 04:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 03:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 02:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 01:00:00 0   0   0   0
2020-08-26 00:00:00 0   0   0   0
```

Code

```
function results_per_interval($lrg_pdo) {
    $now = time();
    print "Current Time: $now<br>";

    $interval_count = 12;
    $duration = 3600;
    
    $modulus = $now % $duration;
    $start_interval = $now + ($duration - $modulus);
    $end_interval  = $start_interval - ($duration * $interval_count);

    $interval = $start_interval;

    print "Interval: $interval<br>";
    print "<table border=1>";
    web_table_header([
        "Interval",
        "Total",
        "Success",
        "Retry",
        "Failed",
    ]);

    while($interval >= $end_interval) {
        $i_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:00',$interval);
        $i_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:00',$interval+$duration);
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
            (SELECT count(*) FROM results WHERE timestamp_created between '$i_start' and '$i_end') as count,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM results WHERE timestamp_created between '$i_start' and '$i_end' and status='success') as success_count,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM results WHERE timestamp_created between '$i_start' and '$i_end' and status='processing') as retry_count,
            (SELECT count(*) FROM results WHERE timestamp_created between '$i_start' and '$i_end' and status='failed') as failed_count";
    
        $r = $lrg_pdo->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        web_table_row([
            $i_start,
            $r->count,
            $r->success_count,
            $r->retry_count,
            $r->failed_count,
        ]);

        $interval = $interval - $duration;
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the dates using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select current_date + interval hour(now()) hour as dt, 1 as n
      union all
      select dt - interval 1 hour, n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 12
     )
select *
from dates;
```

You can then put this into your query:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select current_date + interval hour(now()) hour as dt, 1 as n
      union all
      select dt - interval 1 hour, n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 12
     )
select d.dt, count(*) as num,
       sum(status = 'success') as num_success,
       sum(status = 'processing') as num_processing,
       sum(status = 'failed') as num_failed
from dates d left join
     results r
     on r.timestamp >= d.dt and
        r.timestamp < d.dt + interval 1 hour
group by d.dt;
```